# Why QChar in Qt code is passed by value instead of const reference?

Tags: c++, qt

In QString constructor and other functions QChar is passed by value, not by const ref: [QString(QChar ch)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-2), however it's a class itself ([class QChar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchar.html)), not a POD type. Why is it passed so?

Comment: Considering that `QChar` handles a "**16-bit** Unicode character", the data inside the class is probably small enough (say, 16 bits?) that copying is trivial. Remember that on a typical modern (32- or 64-bit) system `int` is 32 bits and that's copied and passed by value without any problems.

Comment: Because value semantics are nice and there is no performance impact.

Comment: Mandatory read: http://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/02/the-value-of-passing-by-value/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `QChar` class in Qt 5.6.2 has a single data member, an `unsigned short`. Accordingly `sizeof(QChar)` will be `2` on most platforms. That’s smaller than your usual pointer (normally 4 or 8 bytes).

So, you can treat a `QChar` the same as you would any other fundamental type. In facts it is designed to work that way because it replaces `char` in the Qt API.

The reason for passing by const ref is efficiency and makes perfect sense for large objects. Passing by value would mean an expensive copy in these circumstances. So you trade that for an added indirection (because under the hood a reference is usually implemented with a pointer) and are better of. For fundamental types that reasoning does not hold. Copying is cheap, so it’s more efficient to pass by value and avoid an added indirection.

Comment: 2 bytes is small indeed, but if more data fields were added to the class in the future - the code would need to be changed...

Comment: @trig-ger - why would the code need to be changed? The same code will work regardless of the size. It is **highly unlikely** that `QChar` could ever grow beyond 32bit, as that would require a language with more than 4 billion characters.

Comment: It will never happen in Qt 5 lifetime. Qt has a strict binary compatibility policy.

Comment: Also, there is no need to. QChar is UTF-16 encoded, i.e. it can handle all 128172 characters defined in current [Unicode 9](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/). If you think that number is too large for 2 bytes, you’re correct. But remember that UTF-16 is a variable length encoding where a character can be either 2 or 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

According to some, it is because a `QChar` is only 2 bytes, while a pointer is 4 or 8 bytes, so it is more efficient.

However, that isn't the full story. Modern machines take the same time to pass an architecture-native pointer as they take to pass a single byte, and in the end it all ends up on either a 32bit or 64bit register. And while it is true that this wasn't the case back in the days, and machines were much slower at passing large integers, their pointers were not 4 or 8 bytes long either. So at best, there is some gain if you say pass a byte by value instead of by reference on a 16bit machine from like 30 years ago.

Remember that the reference, if actually passed, is just a pointer, so the inefficiency has more to do with using an extra layer of indirection. Why pass a pointer just to go look for that object somewhere else in memory, when you can pass the object itself. At least theoretically.

In practice, compilers are very good at optimizing. Any type of function that could be called in a hot spot and could likely result in a tangible overhead would be trivial and thus would be inlined by the compiler instead of called, so no passing of parameter takes place. If you compare two trivial functions, one that passes by value and the other by reference, you will realize they result in exactly the same machine code.

So, it is passed by value because that's what makes sense theoretically, even if it doesn't matter in practice. And because you save a little on typing. You'd only need to pass by reference if you want to modify the object outside the function.